# SqlConnection Class is missing from Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Sir,

Made an `activity page` and declared `System.Data.SqlClient` to connect it with `MSSQL`. Then I have declared `SqlConnection` class, but it showing me error as `The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**below is .xaml code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Enter First Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Last Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Enter Contact No"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText3" />
    <Button
        android:text="Save Data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/saveDatabtn1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**.cs code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MobAppDB
{
    [Activity(Label = "InsertData_Act")]
    public class InsertData_Act : Activity
    {
        static string Constr = "Data Source=HP-PC;Initial Catalog=UserMobileData;User Id=sa;Password=sa@123;";

        //Connection Class
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constr);

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //Initialize Controls
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.InsertData);
            Button butt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.saveDatabtn1);
            butt.Click += saveDatabtn1_Click;


        }

        private void saveDatabtn1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql support for Xamarin.android ? I don't think you are really looking MYSql db which has to be access remotely as none of the platform supports it .

I think what you are looking for is SQLite db not Mysql.

Sqlite is light weight database made for mobile platform.

and the class name you are looking for is.

SQLiteConnection.

More on this you can read from 
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/

Realm db is another best approach for offline data storage which requires no SQL knowledge.

But you are really looking to support Mysql db in Xamarin.android. Go for it . I won't recommend it at all

https://components.xamarin.com/view/mysql-plugin

Comment: Sir need to use sql server

Comment: It is on server?

Comment: Sir Sql server is on different machine Therefore I need to access it via IP address. but when I use SqlConnection class, then it dosen't support Sql related any class or method.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid is there is a direct support in Xamarin.android , but you can check the plugin I mentioned above .

https://components.xamarin.com/view/mysql-plugin

Comment: Sir, is there no support of SQL Server with xamarin Apps on Visual Studio ?

Comment: See thats not how it works bro , when u want to work with Sqlserver remotely , you need web services ,web services talk to your db , and you talk to web services .

Comment: This link [https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/] might be useful